# Full page background image not centered and too big in IE (tried the ms-filter fix already)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, center, parallax

I have a problem with the full page background image of my parallax site in IE (all versions, doesn't work even in IE9+). Everything works perfectly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but in IE, my background image is oddly big (zoomed in) and the background starts from the horizontal center of the image. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

And this is how it should be displayed (as it does in other browsers):

[image]

The website can be seen live at http://somniumensemble.fi/.

I'm using Bootstrap and Keith Clark's Pure CSS Parallax tutorial (http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/).

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="unesi" class="parallax__group">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title" id="kuvaus">Unesi ääni</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <!-- Back layer with the bg image -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#unesi .parallax__layer--back {
   background: url('../somnium1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
   background-size: 100%;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../somnium1.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../somnium1.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

As you can see, I've already tried the ms filter which is often suggested to fix these problems. I guess it scales the image to the whole page, but doesn't fix the positioning. I also have background-position: center center. I can't use a fixed background image with absolute positioning because it messes up the parallax build of the site (which, in any case, doesn't really work in IE).

ANY help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: How about using background-size:cover ??

Comment: @FarzadYZ I tried that, the result is the same: works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but doesn't fix the problem in IE.